# How to create a bar chart with floating bars to show time ranges?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I need to create an excel chart that shows the start time and duration of different processes. I have the start time and runtime as date/time values and minutes. The purpose is to compare them to get a visual overwiew of different processes starttime and duration and overlapping.

So my goal is something like a bar chart where the x-axis has times starting at 00:00 and ending at 24:00 where the different bars do not start right at the Y-axis (00:00) but instead start at the starttime time of the process and end at the end time of the process (could be calculated if required, or just use the duration to figure out the length of the bar).

Please look at the pic to see what I try to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way probably is to use a horizontal, stacked bar chart:

- you need your data in two columns: start and duration
- select it, then go to insert - (charts) - horizontal bar - stacked
- format "start" series:

  - no fill
  - no border

[image]

Comment: Great and simple. One more thing I need: How can I add the names of the processes to the y axis instead of some random/increasing numbers?

Comment: just include it in a separate column, see the update picture